# Attempting to splice a recurring item out of a list

Tags: list, parsing, iteration

I have extracted files from an online database that consist of a roughly 100 titles. Associated with each of these titles is a DOI number, however, the DOI number is different for each title. To program this endeavor, I converted the contents of the website to a list. I then created  for loop to iterate through each item of the list. What I want the program to do is iterate through the entire list and find where it says "DOI:" then to take the number which follows this. However, with the for loop I created, all it seems to do is print out the first DOI number, then terminates. How to I make the loop keep going once I have found the first one.

Here is the code:

```
resulttext = resulttext.split()
print(resulttext)
for item in resulttext:
    if item == "DOI:":
        DOI=resulttext[resulttext.index("DOI:")+1] #This parses out the DOI, then takes the item which follows it
        print(DOI)
```

Comment: The loop doesn't terminate, you are using just one 'if' case, hence when DOI is seen, some operation is performed & for the rest,, it doesn't has any operation to perform. You are doing nothing for any other condition

Comment: Can you edit your question and include a few examples of `resulttext` with and without DOI?